# unindent does not match any outer indentation level python3.6.4

Tags: python

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
path='dataSet'

def getImagesWithID(path):
    imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
 print imagePaths 

getImageWithID(path)
```

this code is not working showing the problem related to title

Comment: Your print statement has bad indentation.  If you read the traceback it would tell you this.

Comment: The error message explains specifically what the problem is... what would you like us to add?

Comment: I would suggest trying the search box perhaps next time and taking a look at a few of the [101 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unindent+does+not+match+any+outer+indentation+level+python).

Answer (score 0):

Align your print statement to the above one and it should work.